# Problem while connecting to postgres server via SSL

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc, ssl-certificate

I tried to connect to the postgres server with the following url :

> jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3456/postgres?**ssl=true**

But i get the following error :

> java.lang.Exception: Exception during getConnection from pool
> Exception occurred during get connection from datasource

```
public Connection connect(String url, Properties info) throws SQLException {
        if (url != null && url.toLowerCase().startsWith(driverPrefix)) {
            Properties props = this.setupConnectProperties(url, info);
            return new JtdsConnection(url, props);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The above mentioned method throws an sql exception when ssl=true but when ssl=require it doesn't throw SQLException.

Why does this occur and how can I fix this?

Comment: Java exceptions are about 800 times longer than what you show, and what you show is not the interesting part of it.  Somewhere there should be given a reason for the failure, not just the fact that it failed.  If you don't specify ssl=true, then does it work?

Comment: Yes when I removed ssl=true it works fine

Comment: Post the whole exception or close the question